# Creating one-to-many relationship between a model and a db table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say i have 2 models, `Poll` and `Answer` . From what i understand, i can create `one-to-many` relationship between them by `$this->hasMany('Answers')` - which will give me access to the db table `answers` from `Poll` model.

But is there a possibility to create this relationship just between the `Poll` model and a `answers` table, without creating `Answer` model?

**Edit**

Additional questions:

1. Is this considered a bad practice?
2. If i don't need all the advantages that using model gives me in a specific table, will working directly with a db table will enhance preformance?

Comment: I guess you could try doing a `join` but why don't you just create a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relationship without an Eloquent Model does not make sense. You can do that without Laravel by using database foreign keys. The purpose of an Eloquent relationship (and of an ORM in general) is to get structured objects when calling the relationship.

```php
$answers = $poll->answers;
echo $answers->last()->title;
```

We use OOP in order to not manipulate raw datas but objects, it is generally a bad practice to not map your database to actual objects. The only exception is for "technical tables" like logs, sessions or job queues.

The question of performance is quite controversial. In a first level, yes, you can improve your performances by using raw requests instead of ORM requests because you have to manage every little detail. But in a professional work it's always better to use your ORM because the gain in readability and maintainability is huge. It will allow you to spent your time in optimization only when it is necessary with great tools like the management of easy/eager loading (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

And, finally, if you want to write pieces of raw SQL request between ORM methods, you can do that with Eloquent (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

`1. But is there a possibility to create this relationship just between the Poll model and a answers table, without creating Answer model?`

No, there isn't. You could use `join` to achieve what you want.

`2. Is this considered a bad practice?`

Not really imo, but I don't understand why you wouldn't make an `Answer` model class. It makes your code more readable and flexible.

`If i don't need all the advantages that using model gives me in a specific table, will working directly with a db table will enhance preformance?`

I don't know for sure but I think querying is faster then using Eloquent, I won't say it's better.